# Can Chef manage multiple "instances" of a system?

Tags: chef-infra

We developing a fairly complicated system which will get deployed to client sites, one of which is our internal instance of the system. Does Chef have the ability to maintain multiple instances of a system which will be configured very differently?

Comment: It's unlikely you're going to use a single chef server to manage both your internal and external customer deployments. The answer is yes provided you understand that the setup of a chef server will be part of your deployment. This is not hard, one could use a service like hosted chef.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as your [cookbooks](http://docs.opscode.com/chef_overview_cookbooks.html) are parameterised well via [attributes](http://docs.opscode.com/chef_overview_attributes.html).

This way, you can configure things by overriding the attributes on different levels, such as [roles](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_roles.html), [nodes](http://docs.opscode.com/chef_overview_nodes.html) and [environments](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_environments.html).

Alternatively, you can also use [data bags](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_data_bags.html) for more complicated data sets.

Chef is a very powerful system and as such takes a while to master. I'd suggest you begin with the tutorials on [learnchef.com](https://learnchef.opscode.com) while using the [docs](http://docs.opscode.com) as reference until you get a good grasp of the essentials.